# Visualizing Points on leaflet with d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, leaflet

I want to render points, coming from a `.json` file through d3 on a leaflet map.
The only three promising articles I found are:
http://bost.ocks.org/mike/leaflet/;

http://bl.ocks.org/sumbera/10463358
and

https://leanpub.com/D3-Tips-and-Tricks/read#leanpub-auto-leaflet-map-with-d3js-objects-that-scale-with-the-map

However, I cannot transfer that to my problem.
The first link does that with `polygons` and the second link is far to complicated. The third one does not seem to work...

Thats what I got.

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>A Leaflet map!</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.css"/>
  <script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.js"></script>
  <script src="d3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

  <style>
    #map{ height: 100% }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

  <div id="map"></div>
  <script>

  // initialize the map
  var map = L.map('map').setView([42.35, -71.08], 13);

  // synchroize d3 and leaflet
  var svg = d3.select(map.getPanes().overlayPane).append("svg"),
  g = svg.append("g").attr("class", "leaflet-zoom-hide");

  // but how to draw the points on the map?!

  // load a tile layer
  L.tileLayer('http://stamen-tiles-{s}.a.ssl.fastly.net/toner/{z}/{x}/{y}.{ext}', {
    minZoom: 0,
    maxZoom: 20,
    ext: 'png'
    }).addTo(map);

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

My problem is: How would I extract the information I need from the `.json` and then, use that as a `.svg` to overlay my leaflet map with?

Citiy data from: Made with Natural Earth. Free vector and raster map data @ naturalearthdata.com.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking @ your cities.json they are all points.

Thus you will have to use this demo to render your points http://bl.ocks.org/sumbera/10463358.

Since you already have points in the correct format so you dont need to  the `reformat function`:

```
function reformat(array) {
                var data = [];
                array.map(function (d, i) {

                    data.push({
                        id: i,
                        type: "Feature",
                        geometry: {
                            coordinates: [+d.longitude, +d.latitude],
                            type: "Point"
                        }


                    });
                });
                return data;
            }
            var geoData = { type: "FeatureCollection", features: reformat(incidents) };
```

Instead you just need to do this:

```
d3.json('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/cyrilcherian/92b8f73dcbbb08fd42b4/raw/087202976663f9f3192bec8f0143cf3bc131c794/cities.json', function(error, incidents) {
      //load the json data
      var geoData = incidents;
      //put the data in the quad tree
      var qtree = d3.geom.quadtree(geoData.features.map(function(data, i) {
        return {
          x: data.geometry.coordinates[0],
          y: data.geometry.coordinates[1],
          all: data
        };
      }));
```

Now use the quad tree to get the points which need to be displayed.

If your are wondering what is quad tree read this [here](https://blog.qburst.com/2014/10/quadtree-simplified/)

Working example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/HSD3B8WEgJ0ucNp3qO3I?p=preview)

**EDIT**

Working example of drawing points sans quad tree optimization is [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/AkvPijzxHPjztDIAqg2a?p=preview)

Hope this helps!

Comment: why would I need to use quadtree to draw a SVG over leaflet? Quadtree identifies points in the windowextend?!

Comment: quad tree is used here to show/draw only the points in the view area. If you draw all the points it will too heavy...and slow..

Comment: yep, I understand that. But that does not explain how I draw a SVG on the leaflet map...  think what I am looking for starts here (http://plnkr.co/edit/HSD3B8WEgJ0ucNp3qO3I?p=preview) somewhere at line 147...

Comment: quad tree is just like a db to store points on js ...if you are not intrested with quad tree then dont use it simple

Comment: Thats the question I have. What would I used instead? What would be the code to draw a SVG on a leaflet map... from there I can start and may include quadtree. But from the links I gave I cannot extract what the necessary lines are, to bring a SVG (maybe just one point) on a leaflet map.

Comment: check the edit section for a simple example sans quad tree

Comment: Whoops, all the plnkrs are gone :(